# Get payload from Expired JWT

Tags: php, jwt

I am using https://github.com/firebase/php-jwt to generate JWT and i am using this token at firebase with 1 hour expiry and using same token at app server to validate request.After 1 hour (Expiry of token) the validation start getting failed with `Uncaught Firebase\JWT\ExpiredException: Expired token in /home/bitnami/vendor/firebase/php-jwt/src/JWT.php:162`.

The expiry of token has nothing to do with the verification because on app side, the login session will stay until user logout. So by just ignoring the expiry can i validate the JWT and get the payload.

Method i am using to generate and validate the JWT

```
<?php

use Firebase\JWT\JWT;
use Firebase\JWT\Key;
require_once ("autoload.php");

function checkJWT($con,$userID,$jwt) {
    $now = new DateTimeImmutable();
    $domainName = "firebase-XXXXX-XXXXX@XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX.iam.gserviceaccount.com";
    $secret_Key  = "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\XXXXXXX--XXXXX---END PRIVATE KEY-----\n";
    $sql = "SELECT JWT,created FROM sample where id = $userID";
    
    $res = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
    $data = mysqli_fetch_array($res);   
    if($data['JWT'] == $jwt){
    $res = openssl_get_privatekey($secret_Key);
     $details = openssl_pkey_get_details($res);
     $publicKey = $details['key'];
        
    
    try{
        $token = JWT::decode($jwt, new Key($publicKey, 'RS256'));
    }catch ( \Firebase\JWT\ExpiredException $exception ){
        // Need to validate the token only on exipry
    }
    
    
    
    $time = $data['created'];
    if ($token->iss !== $domainName || $token->uid !== $userID || $token->created !== $time){
        return false;           
    }else{
        return true;            
    }

    } 
    
}


function generateJWT($con,$userID,$cretedTime) {
    $domainName = "firebase-XXXXX-XXXXX@XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX.iam.gserviceaccount.com";
    $secret_Key  = "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\XXXXXXX--XXXXX---END PRIVATE KEY-----\n";
    
    $date   = time();
    //$expire_at     = $date->modify('+3 minutes')->getTimestamp(); // Add 60 seconds   

    $request_data = [
    'iss'  => $domainName, 
    'sub' => $domainName,
    'aud' => "https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/google.identity.identitytoolkit.v1.IdentityToolkit",
    'iat'  => $date,         // Issued at: time when the token was generated
                              // Issuer
    'exp' => $date+(60*60),  // Maximum expiration time six month in seconds //15778476 
    'uid' => $userID,                     // User name
    'created' => $cretedTime,                     // User name
    ];
    

    
    
     $newToken = JWT::encode($request_data,$secret_Key,'RS256');
     $sqlQuery = "UPDATE `sample` SET  `JWT` =  '$newToken' WHERE  `id` = '$userID'";
    
     if(mysqli_query($con, $sqlQuery)){
        return $newToken; 
    }else {
        return 'Unable To Process';

    }
    
}       


?>
```

I don't want to reissue token on expiry. All i need to validate and get the payload for authorized access. Any help please.

Answer (score 0):

Look at how it's done [in the library](https://github.com/firebase/php-jwt/blob/main/src/JWT.php#L110), it's pretty simple.

You can do it this way:

```php
try {
    // ...
} catch (\Firebase\JWT\ExpiredException $exception) {
    $tks = \explode('.', $jwt);
    $payload = JWT::jsonDecode(JWT::urlsafeB64Decode($tks[1]));
    if (\is_array($payload)) {
        $payload = (object) $payload;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks i will check this code out & get back to you

Comment: I tried but this code wont print anything. Also can i still check if the JWT is valid (Ignore Expiry) and not modified externally ? It enters in catch block in expired token check `if($exception->getMessage() == "Expired token"){  $tks = explode('.', $jwt);    $payload = JWT::jsonDecode(JWT::urlsafeB64Decode($tks[1]));    if (is_array($payload)) {     $payload = (object) $payload;     print_r($payload);    }`